# OAuth for Jersey

Tags: rest, oauth, jersey, signature, hmacsha1

The RESTful system is constructed by using jersey. 
The error occurs when signature is verified and it is not possible to execute it. 
Please teach if the person who understands the cause enters.

MacOS X
Jetty
Google App Engine

(Client)

```
@GET
@Path("/oauth_client")
@Produces("text/html")
public String oauthClient() {

    OAuthParameters params = new OAuthParameters().consumerKey("hoge").signatureMethod("HMAC-SHA1").timestamp().nonce().version("1.1").token("sho1get");
    OAuthSecrets secrets = new OAuthSecrets().consumerSecret("testtest").tokenSecret("testtest");

    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource resource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/v1/test/oauth_provider");

    OAuthClientFilter filter = new OAuthClientFilter(client.getProviders(), params, secrets);
    resource.addFilter(filter);

    System.out.println("==== Client =====");
    return resource.get(String.class);
}
```

(Provider)

```
@Path("/oauth_provider")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String oauthProvider(@Context HttpContext context) {

    OAuthServerRequest request = new OAuthServerRequest(context.getRequest());
    OAuthParameters params = new OAuthParameters().readRequest(request);
    OAuthSecrets secrets = new OAuthSecrets().consumerSecret("hoge").tokenSecret("testtest");
    String timestamp = params.getTimestamp();

    try {
        /* The error occurs here. */
        if (OAuthSignature.verify(request, params, secrets)) {
            return "OK";
        }
    } catch (OAuthSignatureException e) {
        log.warning(e.getMessage());
    } catch (UniformInterfaceException e) {
        log.warning(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warning(e.getMessage());
    }

    return "ERROR";
}
```

(Error)

```
[java] 2011/03/09 4:52:07 com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse mapMappableContainerException
 [java] SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
 [java] java.lang.AbstractMethodError
 [java]         at com.sun.jersey.oauth.signature.OAuthSignature.constructRequestURL(OAuthSignature.java:193)
 [java]         at com.sun.jersey.oauth.signature.OAuthSignature.elements(OAuthSignature.java:218)
 [java]         at com.sun.jersey.oauth.signature.OAuthSignature.verify(OAuthSignature.java:117)
 [java]         at jp.tryden.resources.test.TestResource.oauthProvider(TestResource.java:259)
 [java]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [java]         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
 [java]         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
 [java]         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
 [java]         at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:100)
 [java]         at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.invokeSubLocator(SubLocatorRule.java:162)
 [java]         at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.SubLocatorRule.accept(SubLocatorRule.java:94)
 [java]         at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:133)
 [java]         at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:83)
 [java]         at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:133)
 [java]         at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:71)
 [java]         at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:990)
 [java]         at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:941)
 [java]         at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:932)
 [java]         at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:384)
 [java]         at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:451)
 [java]         at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:632)
 [java]         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
 [java]         at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:58)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 [java]         at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 [java]         at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
 [java]         at com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:70)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
 [java]         at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:349)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
 [java]         at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
 [java] 2011/03/09 4:52:07 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you update your machine with the latest MacOS Java update? http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4562

The update is causing the Google App Engine dev_server to crash, and may be affecting you as well.  It's unknown who is to blame but an appengine bug has been filed here: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=4712

If a number of people star the issue, we may get a faster response.